# Using DaprClient with Redis - how to read/write a value without prefixing it with the application name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, microservices, dapr

Using `DaprClient.GetStateAsync`, `DaprClient.GetStateEntryAsync`, and `DaprClient.SaveStateAsync` with a key value of `variablename`, whenever I read from/write to Redis, it prefixes the `variablename` with the name of my application. This is what it looks like in my Redis cache:

```
appname||variablename
```

This behavior matches the documentation: https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/state-management/query-state-store/query-redis-store/

However, I have a situation where I **do not** want to have this application name prefix, so that I can write a value from one application and read it from another. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible, or discouraged if somehow technically possible. The documentation explains:

> Dapr state stores are key/value stores. To ensure data compatibility, Dapr requires these data stores follow a fixed key scheme. For general states, the key format is:
>
> `<App ID>||<state key>`

See: https://docs.dapr.io/reference/api/state_api/#key-scheme